# How do I change the language of games on Steam?

Tags: steam, language-support

I'm in love with Valve for providing games on Linux! But here is the problem: **I'm French** and would like to have games in my native language (I have the problem with DOTA and Borderlands 2).

How can I get them in French ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, my language was in english, that's why my games were in english.

> Attention, the servers localization is not the language of games. That's why I was disturb.

Comment: Out of curiosity: How did you conclude that the server's localization affects the display language of your games?

Comment: I never conclude that. Actually the localization option is more visible than the language choice.